# making a computational field based on other fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-admin

I want to ask about if i can make a field that display the result of subtraction of 2 other Date Fields in Admin side ?

Can anyone help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

In the admin? Sure: not a field, but a method that displays in the list display.

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('field1', 'field2', 'mymethod')

    def my_method(self, obj):
        return obj.field1 - obj.field2
```

Comment: Thanks alot, yes in the admin , but they are all DateFields

Comment: That should still work with datefields, except that the result will be a timedelta object. You'll need to convert it to something useful - how would you like the difference to be displayed? Number of days?

Comment: again thank you very much, yes i Want it number of days.

Comment: please if U have a solution help me :( i didn't solve the problem until Know

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. This code works exactly as given. What *precisely* is the problem?